# How to get 'html string attributes'

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

```
"Site is <a href='javascript:;' xid='01' gid='02' rid='03' >TEST</a> is here "
```

This is a string with what seems like an 'a' tag inside. I need to get the 'xid', 'gid', and 'rid' values.

Comment: don't use a regex, use a dom parser.

Comment: Your suggestion worked. Thanks. I did the following:

`let parser = new DOMParser();
                    let doc = parser.parseFromString(content, "text/html");
                    var xid = doc.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].getAttribute('xid');
                    var gid = doc.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].getAttribute('gid');`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you want to get a atributes xid, gid, rid.
You need  get link and get atributes. **For example**:

```
let link = document.querySelector('a');
if(link!==null){
    let xid  = a.getAttribute('xid');
    let gid  = a.getAttribute('gid');
    let rid  = a.getAttribute('rid');
}
```

It is faster than using regex;

If you has only string, you can add this string to dom and get current attributes.
Use regex in not true way , because  your code will not  be flex , and sometimes you can has bugs.